# php mysql insert/update field name show

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, insert

I have a problem in my DB there is a fieldname 'show'
in I have a php script that updates table or insert and everything is working to the field name 'show' even if I change it to 'showz' it works!
I think it is a glitch here is a part of the php code!

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO db.table (mid, name, show) VALUES ('".$row['mid']."',     '".$row['name']."', '".$row['show']."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '".$row['name']."',  show = '".$row['show']."'");
```

I tried to put the show thing in 'show' , `show` , "show" nothing helps!

Comment: `show` keyword is reserved by *MySQL*, use `\`show\``

Comment: You said you tried to put `show` into backticks \`show\`, which would be correct, as you can see in all three answers. Are you sure, you put **both** occurences of `show` into backticks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS show is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html), you need to enclose it in backticks (`) if you use it as a table or column name

```
`show`
```

Comment: Thanks I used that but when I copy/paste it from here it works could it have to do something with my notepad++

Answer (score 4):

that's because `show` is a reserved word (like `insert`, `update`, `order` etc). You can read about reserved words here: [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

In order to use a reserved word as a field name you need to escape it with backticks (`) like so:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO db.table (mid, name, `show`) VALUES ('".$row['mid']."',     '".$row['name']."', '".$row['show']."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '".$row['name']."',  `show` = '".$row['show']."'");
```

This tells mysql to treat it as a field rather than use it in its reserved word meaning.

I find it's good practice to always escape my table and field names with backticks like so:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (`mid`, `name`, `show`) VALUES ('".$row['mid']."',     '".$row['name']."', '".$row['show']."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = '".$row['name']."',  `show` = '".$row['show']."'");
```

Answer (score 3):

you are using reserved keyword use backticks

[**Table 9.2. Reserved Words in MySQL 5.0.96**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

[image]

so use like

```
`show`
```

rather warping all colon name in backticks is good approach

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (`mid`, `name`, `show`) VALUES ('".$row['mid']."',     '".$row['name']."', '".$row['show']."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = '".$row['name']."',  `show` = '".$row['show']."'");
```

---

**Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958)